# Scipy least squares: is it possible to optimize for two error functions simultaneously?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

For this particular work, I am using scipy optimize to try find the best parameters that fit two different models at the same time.

```
model_func_par = lambda t, total, r0, theta:  np.multiply((total/3),(1+2*r0),np.exp(-t/theta))
model_func_perp = lambda t, total, r0, theta:  np.multiply((total/3),(1-r0),np.exp(-t/theta))
```

After this I create two error functions by subtractig the raw data, and plug it into scipy.optimize.leastsq(). As you can see I have two different equations with the same r0 and theta parameters - I have to find the parameters that fit best both equations (in theory, r0 and theta should be the same for both equations, but because of noise and experimental errors etc I am sure this won't be quite the case.

I guess I could do a separate optimization for each equation and perhaps take an average of the two results, but I wanted to see if anyone knows of a way to do one optimization for both.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any specific reason to use `np.multiply`? Since the typical mathematical operators are overloaded for `np.ndarray`s, it's more convenient to write (and read):

```py
model1 = lambda t, total, r0, theta: (total/3) * (1+2*r0) * np.exp(-t/theta) 
model2 = lambda t, total, r0, theta: (total/3) * (1-r0) * np.exp(-t/theta)
```

To answer your question: AFAIK this isn't possible with `scipy.optimize.least_squares`. However, a very simple approach would be to minimize the sum of  least squares residuals

```
min || model1(xdata, *coeffs) - ydata ||^2 + || model2(xdata, *coeffs) - ydata ||^2
```

like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.linalg import norm

# your xdata and ydata as np.ndarrays
# xdata = np.array([...])
# ydata = np.array([...])

# the objective function to minimize
def obj(coeffs):
    return norm(model1(xdata,*coeffs)-ydata)**2 + norm(model2(xdata,*coeffs)-ydata)**2

# the initial point (coefficients)
coeffs0 = np.ones(3)

# res.x contains your coefficients
res = minimize(obj, x0=coeffs0)
```

However, note that this isn't a complete answer. A better approach would be to formulate it as a multi-objective optimization problem. You may take a look at [pymoo](https://pymoo.org/) for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you soo much, I have been getting familiar with scipy.minimize and trying to get a better fit, and thanks for drawing pymoo to my attention! About numpy arithmetic operations - honestly I thought it is more efficient for arrays, out of curiosity what do you mean the mat operators are overloaded for numpy arrays?

Comment: It means that e.g. `a + b` is the same as `np.add(a,b)` for two numpy arrays, since the `+`-operator is *overloaded* such that it calls `np.add` internally. The same holds true for the other arithmetic operators.

Comment: Sorry to pester you again, just curious why are you squaring each norm of each difference in the objective function? I am trying to determine the chi-squared to estimate the accuracy of the fits for each pixel and I am getting huge values, than I realised it's likely because the objective function is already squaring both components

Comment: Squaring the norm yields fewer rounding errors when evaluating the gradient by finite differences. Since we don't pass a gradient, `minimize` approximates it automatically by finite differences.